# How to add a method that tests if an object is empty?

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I have found the [following implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) in python of the priority queue.

I have some questions.

1. How to add a method that tests if the heap is empty. I tried the following:

```py
   def is_empty(self):        
        return not any(self.heap)
```

It's not correct since the remove is handled through the `_REMOVED` thing.

2. What is `REMOVED` ? does it have a name in python (global variable ?), when to use it? is it a good practice?
3. Why there is `object` in `class PriorityQueue(object)` ?

Comment: `_REMOVED`  is a class variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'heap' in this context is simply a python list. Simply checking if the length of the list is zero should do the trick of evaluating if it's empty.

Update:

```
def is_empty(self):
    return not self.heap
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed.

Comment: Per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) ("For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false"), the correct way to do this is just `return not self.heap`; checking length and comparing to zero just adds overhead.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you. I didn't think of doing it that way, but I agree checking the length is unnecessary overhead.